Kafka Infrastructure Set Up
I am new to Kafka, I have got a requirement to receive around 9000 messages per second, size of each message is around 20 KB.
Can someone suggest, what are the ideal number of VMs required for: Zookeeper, Broker, if the configuration of each VM is 16 Cores, 16 GB RAM.
I know this is not a straightforward question, however I have to place a VM procurement request. Any feedback/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Kafka will remove Zookeeper completely within a year or so, so start without it. That being said, 3 of each is a starting point
